# Laravel, return all data on single model row recursively through relationships

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

Given a model and an id. Get all $fillable data for that row. This is including data from relationships between models, so if there's a relationship with another model. It needs to fetch all fillable data from the related model too. And if that related model has relationships, we need to follow those as well.

I've tried lots of stuff so far but it's all following the same general thought process. What I have so far on my most recent attempt is below. Further information: Each model has protected $fillable and an array called $getPossibleRelations which has a list of relationship names used by that model. There are __get functions for fillable, and possible relations on the models.

```
    $item = $model->where('id',$id);

    function deepProcess($item) {
        $fillable = $item->find(1)->getFillable();
        $item = call_user_func_array(array($item, 'select'), $fillable);//select only fillable fields
        $possibleRelations = $item->find(1)->getPossibleRelations();

        foreach ($possibleRelations as $rel) {//eager load any possible relations
            $item = $item->with([
                $rel => function($query) {//reaches here ok, below recursion fails
                    $query = deepProcess($query);
                }
            ]);
        }
        return $item;
    }
    $item = deepProcess($item)->get()->toArray();
    dd($item);
```

Within the eager load the query needs to somehow loop back through the same function. And it needs to make sure it doesn't go back through a relation it has already been through (I used get_class() to check for that in a previous attempt).

I'm a bit lost as to how I should do this

Here's another attempt I made which is also flawed in many obvious ways.

```
    $item = $model->where('id',$id);
    $checkedModels = [];
    $result = [];
    function deepFetch($item,&$result,&$checkedModels,$className) {

        if (in_array($className,$checkedModels)) {
            return; //we've already added bits from this model
        }
        array_push($checkedModels,$className);
        if($className == 'Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection') {
            dd($item);
        }
        var_dump('loop count');
        $fillable = $item->get()[0]->getFillable();
        $possibleRelations = $item->get()[0]->getPossibleRelations();

        foreach($item->select($fillable)->get() as $row) {
            array_push($result,$row);
        }

        foreach ($possibleRelations as $rel) {
            dd($item->get());
            $newItem = $item->get()->$rel;
            deepFetch($newItem,$result[$rel],$checkedModels,get_class($newItem));
        }
    }
    deepFetch($item,$result,$checkedModels,get_class($model));
```

Comment: That will be really hard to achieve (read: unmaintainable, hard to reason about code). The simple answer would be to have `protected $with = [relationships]` in your models. But there are problems with that, such as a) especially in many-to-many relationships you could get into infinite recursion b) you might have use cases where you don't want to load some. Can you provide some examples why you need this and how deep you expect it to go?

Comment: @devk so the protected $with variable you've suggested is essentially what I've already done but I've called it $possibleRelations. The whole thing is driving me up the wall. Yep many to many is a problem, there needs to be a check to make sure you haven't revisited a model you've already been to, I have a working version of this in my second attempt. For b, yep, that'll be restricted by only having desired relations stored under $with/$possibleRelations. This is part of a booking system I'm working on... (cont next comment)

Comment: ...where essentially I want to be able to pick out an id for a model and use that to create a 'profile' page for all related data to that. So if you're booking in a dog for x, it'll have an owner or multiple, the owners will have addresses, billing addresses, the dogs have vaccines, different sizes, different rates for each size etc. If you click on the owner it'll need to show their dog(s), addresses etc, all bookings they've made and more. If you click a booking show the dog being booked, the dogs owners etc. I think you get it. This is a pet project of mine I started recently.

Comment: It's of course not completely needed, I could create a method for every model to fetch the data they each need. But I've always liked making things a crazy dynamic, it's a fun problem. I just lack the depth of understanding needed of how eloquent builders, queries, collections etc tie in together

Comment: Yeah, it does seem like an interesting problem. I don't have a project at hand where I could easily test some solutions and I'm not sure I could come up with a good one quickly anyway, so I won't be of much help. But seeing your tries, I would recommend not doing any query within the recursive function, as it will be a huge performance loss if you want to get multiple models (which means you'd want to make `getPossibleRelations()` static). And the recursive function should preferably return a query of multiple nested `$q->with(..)` calls. I'd suggest going for an easier solution really.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
        $item = $model->where('id',$id);

        function deepProcess($item,$depth,$currentRel,$currentRelClasses) {
            foreach ($depth->first()->getPossibleRelations() as $rel) {//eager load any possible relations
                $newRel = $rel;
                if ($currentRel !== '') {
                    $newRel = $currentRel.'.'.$rel;// $newRel example, dog.owner.addresses
                }

                $futureItemCollection = $depth->first()->$rel->first();
                if (!$futureItemCollection) {
                    continue; // no relationship found from $depth through $rel
                }
                array_push($currentRelClasses, get_class($futureItemCollection));//we need to check for the future relationship before the recursive call
                if (max(array_count_values($currentRelClasses)) > 1) {//if we've hit the same relation more than once then skip current iteration
                    continue;
                }

                // $fillable = $futureItemCollection->getFillable();
                // $item = $item->with([$newRel => function($query) use($fillable) {
                //     call_user_func_array([$query, 'select'], $fillable);//select only fillable fields
                // }]);
                $item = $item->with($newRel);//selecting only fillable fields wasn't working, likely due to unexpected fields being required
                $item = deepProcess($item, $depth->first()->$rel,$newRel,$currentRelClasses);
            }
            return $item;
        }
        $item = deepProcess($item,$item,'',[get_class($item->first())])->get()->toArray();
        dd($item);
```

Mostly works, it's rough, and I couldn't get the select statement to work (which is why it's commented out and a plain with(relation) is used instead. It works for my purposes though